# Display Excel data table with hyperlink on webpage using Python flask

Tags: python, excel, pandas, flask

I am trying to display excel data on webpage using python flask. There are two columns in the excel sheet which contains website address as (https://www.example.com/) and they are hyperlinked. Pandas data frame is used for reading and displaying Excel data on the webpage. When the code is run, Excel table is displaying on the webpage. But the hyperlinks are not displaying.

I tried the following

1. Edited Excel column with website address as

   ```
    =HYPERLINK("https://www.example.com/")
   ```

   that didn't work.
2. Edited Excel column as  [this is link](https://www.example.com/)

   that didn't work either.

I want to display data table with hyperlinks in the respective columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your flask template you should display your link inside an anchor element

```
<a href="{{link}}">Go to x</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: _I am trying to display excel data on webpage using python flask_, I understand that OP wants to display the content of the excel inside a webpage using HTML